# error message in discord bot? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a event and command handler evrything look well but when i run my `,hello` command i get an error here is the error:

if(!message.content.startsWith(Prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

here is the code:

```
module.exports = (Discord, Client, message) => {
    const Prefix = ',';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(Prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const Command = Client.commands.get(cmd);

    if(Command) Command.execute(Client, message, args, Discord, Random, RadnomPuppy);
}
```

I don't see any problems

Comment: the ```,hello``` command is my only command for now

Answer (score 0):

You have to many parameters to your function, so message is undefined.
Should look like this:

```js
client.on("message", (msg)=>{
    const Prefix = ',';
    if(!msg.content.startsWith(Prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const Command = Client.commands.get(cmd); // Have the commands part in file scope, to access it here.

    if(Command) Command.execute(Client, msg, args, Discord, Random, RadnomPuppy);

})
```

Comment: so should i replace every msg with message

Comment: this does not work im getting a new error saying client is not defined in Client.on("message", (message)=>{

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = (Discord, Client, message) => {
    const Prefix = ',';
    if(!message.content.startsWith(Prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(Prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const Command = Client.commands.get(cmd);

   if(Command) Command.execute(Client, message, args, Discord);
}
```

I had to remove the random and random-puppy from the `if(Command) Command.execute(Client, message, args, Discord);` line